# is there time complexity difference between making visited by set and making it by array when doing dfs?

Tags: python

```
    import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10 ** 6)

n, m = map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split())

notZero = set()

# 행렬만들기, 0아닌것은 기록해줌
matrix = []
for i in range(n):
    tmp = list(map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split()))
    for j in range(m):
        if tmp[j] != 0:
            notZero.add((i,j))
    matrix.append(tmp)

# 동 서 남 북
dr = [0, 0, 1, -1]
dc = [1, -1, 0, 0]

# 해당 위치에서 주변 0 세기
def around_zero(row, col):
    cnt = 0

    for i in range(4):
        newR = row + dr[i]
        newC = col + dc[i]

        # 첫 마지막 행열은 항상 바다
        if 0 <= newR < n and 0 <= newC < m:
            if matrix[newR][newC] == 0:
                cnt += 1
    return cnt

# dfs하며 깊이만큼 cnt 더해줌
def dfs(row, col): # O(n)
    global cnt
    cnt += 1
    visited[row][col] = True

    for i in range(4):
        newR = row + dr[i]
        newC = col + dc[i]

        if 0 < newR < n-1 and 0 < newC < m-1 and not visited[newR][newC]:
            if matrix[newR][newC] != 0:
                dfs(newR, newC)


ans = 0
while True: 
    ans += 1

    # 전부 다 녹을때까지 덩어리 분리 X
    if len(notZero) == 0:
        print(0)
        break
    
    # 이거 같은 시간대에 미리 녹인쪽이 다른 쪽에 영향을 주면 안됨 - 일괄업데이트 필요
    update = []  # 넣고 빼는데 시간이 너무 드는데, 그렇다고 바로 업데이트하자니 이상하게 녹음
    for i in notZero: # zero 아닌것들 모두 녹여줌
        cnt = around_zero(i[0], i[1]) 
        newVal = matrix[i[0]][i[1]] - cnt
        if newVal <= 0: 
            update.append((i[0], i[1], 0))
        else:
            update.append((i[0], i[1], newVal))
    
    for i in update:
        if i[2] == 0: # 0된애들은 빼줌
            notZero.remove((i[0], i[1]))

        matrix[i[0]][i[1]] = i[2]
    
    # 0아닌것들 중 암거나 dfs해서, 0 아닌것들의 길이보다 짧으면 끝냄
    """
    visited 배열 말고, set에 (로우,컬럼) 저장하는 식으로 하면 시간초과 나고
    배열 쓰면 시간초과 안나는데, 둘다 O(1)아님??
    """
    visited = [[0] * m for _ in range(n)]
    for i in notZero:
        cnt = 0
        dfs(i[0], i[1])
        if cnt < len(notZero):
            print(ans)
            exit()
        break
```

This is dfs code that solves [this problem](https://www.acmicpc.net/problem/2573).
(it is in korean)

In this code, I made visited by multi dimension array,
this code passes time limit,
but when I make visited as set, and pass elements like tuple(row, col)
and check if visited by (row, col) in visited, it gives me time limit
I thought there would be no difference because finding something in set is O(1) time, while finding something in array by index is O(1) too. Can anyone tell me what is difference??

below is code using visited as set..

```
from collections import deque
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10 ** 6)

n, m = map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split())

notZero = set()

# 행렬만들기, 0아닌것은 기록해줌
matrix = []
for i in range(n):
    tmp = list(map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split()))
    for j in range(m):
        if tmp[j] != 0:
            notZero.add((i,j))
    matrix.append(tmp)

# 동 서 남 북
dr = [0, 0, 1, -1]
dc = [1, -1, 0, 0]

# 해당 위치에서 주변 0 세기
def around_zero(row, col):
    cnt = 0

    for i in range(4):
        newR = row + dr[i]
        newC = col + dc[i]

        if 0 <= newR < n and 0 <= newC < m:
            if matrix[newR][newC] == 0:
                cnt += 1
    return cnt

# dfs하며 깊이만큼 cnt 더해줌
def dfs(row, col): # O(n)
    global cnt
    cnt += 1
    visited.add((row,col))

    for i in range(4):
        newR = row + dr[i]
        newC = col + dc[i]

        if 0 < newR < n-1 and 0 < newC < m-1 and (newR, newC) not in visited:
            if matrix[newR][newC] != 0:
                dfs(newR, newC)


ans = 0
while True: 
    ans += 1

    # 전부 다 녹을때까지 덩어리 분리 X
    if len(notZero) == 0:
        print(0)
        break
    
    # 이거 같은 시간대에 미리 녹인쪽이 다른 쪽에 영향을 주면 안됨 - 일괄업데이트 필요
    update = []  # 넣고 빼는데 시간이 너무 드는데, 그렇다고 바로 업데이트하자니 이상하게 녹음
    for i in notZero: # zero 아닌것들 모두 녹여줌
        cnt = around_zero(i[0], i[1]) 
        newVal = matrix[i[0]][i[1]] - cnt
        if newVal <= 0: 
            update.append((i[0], i[1], 0))
        else:
            update.append((i[0], i[1], newVal))
    
    for i in update:
        if i[2] == 0: # 0된애들은 빼줌
            notZero.remove((i[0], i[1]))

        matrix[i[0]][i[1]] = i[2]
    
    # 0아닌것들 중 암거나 dfs해서, 0 아닌것들의 길이보다 짧으면 끝냄
    visited = set()
    for i in notZero:
        cnt = 0
        dfs(i[0], i[1])
        if cnt < len(notZero):
            print(ans)
            exit()
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

If programs A and B both have time complexity of O(1), this means that there are fixed finite timespans t_A and t_B that are upper bounds for the execution times, regardless of input size.

All we can conclude from this about the execution times of A and B for any particular input is that they are not greater than t_A and t_B, respectively. There is no implication that the two execution times had to be equal for the same input.